# How do I get the post parameters needed with fiddler?

Tags: c#, fiddler

I am currently trying to automate my login to Spotify without using the API.
the reason why I am not using the API is because I am currently learning HttpWebRequest With C# and fiddler because I feel like it could be good skillsets to have.

I know how it works, with posting the bytes to the server but how do I know what parameters I need?
I am currently learning Fiddler so I am not entierly sure on how to get the post parameters.

It usually looks something like this (Example from Google)

```
$"username=test&password=test&g-recaptcha-response=sometoken&mod=www&ssl=0&dest=community";
```

You see how the username and password is there, That whole line there would be the data that I would have to post. (Obvioiously with some valid username and password)

How do I properly get the post parameters with Fiddler.
And if Fiddler is not the tool, what would be the better option?

Comment: you can use Postman for calling api url is : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: In what sense how to get? You just view your request in fiddler and see parameters (for example in "request" > "raw" tab).